# Using jQuery to retrieve IDs of several DIVs and store in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a "template" creation system with html, jQuery and PHP. So the interface is very basic, buttons that currently add divs, these divs are to have content such as buttons, textareas, checkboxes and such.

When I click a button, the div is added; now i also want to store this new div ID into an array with jQuery and at the same time output this array into a separate div with the ID of overview.

My current script looks like this:

```
function getSteps() {
        $("#template").children().each(function(){
            var kid = $(this);
            //console.log(kid.attr('id'));
            $('div.overview').append(kid.attr('id'))
        });
    }

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var btnID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('<div></div>', {
            text: btnID,
            id: btnID,
            class: item,
        }).appendTo('div.template');
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getSteps();
    });
```

Now, the function getSteps is where I want to retrieve the ID's of all my divs and store them into an array. When I click one of my buttons, I want them to add a div with an ID into my #template div.

I get an error in my console in chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
(anonymous function)createtemplate.php:111
f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

I'm a bit lost and would love a push into the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce a live demo to reproduce your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), using your rendered HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You could do (to retrieve the ID's of all the divs and store them into an array. )

```
function getSteps() {
    var ids = [];
    $("#template").children().each(function(){
        ids.push(this.id);
    });
    return ids;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var arrayOfIds = getSteps();
});
```

Comment: You can also use `.map(...).get()` to map elements to their IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because you're trying to use a variable called *item* that doesn't exist. I guess you want to give a class called *item*, in which case you should write

```
class:"item",
```

Also, you're appending the new divs to a element with **class** "template", and your getSteps function is searching for an element with **id** "template".

Think that with your code, the getSteps function executes once, when the DOM is ready. If you want to refresh the list of id's every time you add a div, you should do it inside your code for click event:

```
function getSteps() {
    $('div.overview').empty();
    $(".template").children().each(function(){
        var kid = $(this);
        //console.log(kid.attr('id'));
        $('div.overview').append(kid.attr('id'))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var btnID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('<div></div>', {
            text: btnID,
            id: btnID,
            class: 'item',
        }).appendTo('div.template');
        getSteps();
    });

});
```